# What does connected-react-router do?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I was reviewing code when I stummbled upon this in reducer

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux"
import { connectRouter } from "connected-react-router"

const rootReducer = (history: any) =>
  combineReducers({
    router: connectRouter(history)
})


export default rootReducer
```

I am not sure what `import { connectRouter } from "connected-react-router"` (Connect-router do).

i went to npm page of the repo and it says,

> Synchronize router state with redux store through uni-directional
> flow (i.e. history -> store -> router -> components).

But I am unable to comprehend the above statement. Can someone please explain me what does the above statement says? with possibly an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you can use connectedRouter to dispatch navigation actions (thats most common use case in my opinion) inside your actions. For example you may want to navigate to protected route after succesful login:

```
import { push } from 'connected-react-router'

export const login = (username, password) => (dispatch) => {

  /* do something before redirection */

  dispatch(push('/home'))
}
```

Comment: Why not just call `history.push('/home')` directly?

Answer (score 0):

Redux has solved cross-multi component state/data sharing problem.  "connected-react-router" basically achieve consistency of the shared data over different layers. The first layer is a "history package" which provides several different implementations for managing session history in JavaScript in various environments. You have also "store", main redux entity, as a second layer. Router and components are the rest of the layers in ascending order.

Source: [connected-react-router doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connected-react-router)
[react router history](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/history)